# Cannot delete rows in SQL Server table inserted from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: sql-server

I used Import and Export Wizard to import data from an Excel spreadsheet in a table in SQL Server. When I tried to delete some rows using the following query I got the message "(0 row(s) affected)".

```
DELETE FROM transactions
WHERE sum_value <= 0.3 AND sum_value > 0
```

However, when I run this query:

```
select * 
from transactions
where sum_value <= 0.3 AND sum_value > 0
```

154 rocords return.

my table:

```
USE BA_ELTRUN
GO

CREATE TABLE transactions(
payer_id numeric(38),
order_number numeric(38),
sum_units numeric(38),
sum_value numeric(38,2),
id_3rd_level numeric(38),
order_date nVarChar(1024),
isCorporate numeric(38),
payment nVarChar(1024),
tk numeric(38)
)
```

a record:

```
payer_id  order_number sum_units sum_value id_3rd_level  order_date                 isCorporate payment  tk
1725577   50090498        1       0.01      140000       2013-10-29 00:00:00.000          0     Cash  32200
```

Does anyone know why the delete statement does not work?

Comment: Add other info .. Scheme Table... Column Type ecc

Comment: Can you include one record from transactions resulting from your `select` query? I would like to see the structure of the table. Also, do you get any errors with `delete` statement?

Comment: FYI: once the rows are in your SQL table, it's irrelevant they were imported from Excel or any other source.

Comment: Is "create table" query enough? Do you want a record from the table?

Comment: @TT. I also read that but why rows are not deleted?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see a record too. Preferably one you get from your select statement

Comment: The source of the data has nothing to do with whether the `WHERE` matches any rows. On the other hand, uncommitted transactions, especially if the SNAPSHOT isolation level is used, will result in strange behaviour when you try to execute statements from different connections or SSMS windows

Comment: @HoneyBadger I add a record

Comment: I'm not confident enough to propose this as an answer, but you may be encountering some implicit data conversion.  Try `DELETE FROM transactions
WHERE sum_value <= 0.3 AND sum_value > 0.0` to make sure `sum_value` in your `WHERE` clause isn't being treated as an `INT`.  If it works, I'll make it an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @LDMJoe "(0 row(s) affected)" is still the message I get

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am new to sql programming and I got confused. Can you explain me your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. I run the query in System database, master. I used this:

`USE DB_name
 GO`

and rows were deleted.

Comment: Classical case of a "PICNIC" problem - *Problem in Chair, not in Computer* :=)